# making an option value selected based on referring URL with PHP

Tags: php, url, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select dropdown with three options in it; based on the referring URL, I need each option to be the one selected (ie selected="selected").

I'm pretty new to PHP but can do it this way:

```
       <?php if (strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"url-1" )) {
            ?>
               <option value="value-1" selected="selected">
            <?
         } else {
            ?>
            <option value="value-1">
            <?
         }                           
      ?>
```

I do this for each of the three options in the dropdown. As said, this works -- but it seems pretty inefficient to repeat the same thing for each option. Anyone got any clues for me? Thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for all for the help, particularly Adnan. Figured this my ideal solution with help from another forum search, as well as your thoughts:

```
<?php 
$options = array(array('value' => 'value-one', 'label' => 'value-one', 'ref' => 'url-one'),array('value' => 'value-two', 'label' => 'value-two', 'ref' => 'url-two'),array('value' => 'value-three', 'label' => 'value-three', 'ref' => 'url-three'),
);  
foreach ($options as $option) {
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $option['ref']) > 0) {
$optSelected = ' selected';
} else {
$optSelected = ''; 
}
echo '<option value="' . $option['value'] . '"' . $optSelected . '>' . $option['label'] .     '</option>';}
?>`
```

Comment: put the 3 values in an array then  loop through it to build the dropdown and mark the appropriate one.

Comment: can you provide a sample referer url?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "cool" way of doing it

```
foreach(array('url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3') as $url){
    echo (strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $url))?'<option value="value-'.substr($url, 4, 1).'" selected>':'<option value="value-'.substr($url, 4, 1).'">';
}
```

note: `selected` attrib is boolean, so you don't need to give it a value, just put it there.

Update: Here's a correction for the code in your comment:

```
foreach (array('url1' => 'value-one', 'url2' => 'value-two', 'url' => 'value-three') as $url => $value){
   echo (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $url))?"<option value=\"$value\" selected>$value</option>":"<option value=\"$value\">$value</option>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having some issues actually getting this to work (BTW, I didn't literally need to have numbers in my values). This is what I got: `<?php foreach (array('url1', 'url2', 'url') as $url); 
foreach (array('value-one', 'value-two', 'value-three') as $value){
echo (strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $url))?'<option value="$value" selected>'.$value.'</option>':'<option value="$value">'.$value.'</option>';
}
?>` Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @SurrealDreams, very interesting, thank you for the addition. Now please check the HTML5 documentation (I think it doesn't any more `up to date`) [selected option](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-option-selected) and [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use switch(case) statement instead? itll stop you from having to call

```
strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"url-1" )
```

multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a foreach loop after storing all the options in an array.

```
<select name="someOption">
<?php foreach (array('option1', 'option2', 'option3') as $option):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option;?>" <?php if (strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$option )):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>
        <?php echo $option;?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Works?